# Prevent 3rd Library Logger to Create Logging File

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the library [AmpliGraph](https://github.com/Accenture/AmpliGraph) to embed some data. But I couldn't prevent the AmpliGraph `FileHandler` to create an empty application.log file. I've tried to clear ampligraph logger handlers, and yet application.log file is still created.

Below is the library's setting of [`FileHandler`](https://github.com/Accenture/AmpliGraph/blob/07ce70ff9e30812ac8f4a34d245d1d5decec27f7/ampligraph/logger.conf#L26-L30):

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=format
args=('application.log',)
```

My logging configuration is as follow:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, ampligraph

[handlers]
keys=stream_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=stream_handler

[logger_ampligraph]
level=INFO
handlers=stream_handler
qualname=ampligraph
propagate=1

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

Comment: I don't see another way than monkeypatching on `import ampligraph`, unfortunately. A library shouldn't configure its own logging anyway, so a PR would make sense.